# MFC CView (CFormView) destruction crash

Tags: c++, mfc, destructor

As per this stackoverflow question:

[What is the correct way to programmatically quit an MFC application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562335/what-is-the-correct-way-to-programmatically-quit-an-mfc-application)

I am using `AfxGetMainWnd()->PostMessage(WM_CLOSE,0,0);` to exit an MFC program. (SDI, CFrameWnd containing a CSplitterWnd with two CFormViews)

As expected, this calls `DestroyWindow()`.

The problem I am facing is that after the derived CFormView destruction, as per MSDN:

> After calling DestroyWindow on a non-auto-cleanup object, the C++ object will still be around, but m_hWnd will be NULL. [[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zba4hah.aspx)]

Now the `CView` destructor is called and at the point it does the

```
CDocument::RemoveView()...
CDocument::UpdateFrameCounts()
```

it fails on the following assert: `ASSERT(::IsWindow(pView->m_hWnd));`

I checked and the `m_hWnd` is already set to NULL in the derived CView destructor called just before.

What am I doing wrong ?

EDIT:

Here is a chart illustrating why I want to send a WM_CLOSE message and not a WM_QUIT.

[image]

I think the answer lays in this [MSDN Technical Note](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zba4hah.aspx), but I can't figure it out.

EDIT 2:

The order that things get called:

1- `AfxGetMainWnd()->PostMessage(WM_CLOSE,0,0);`

2- `Derived CFrameWnd::OnClose()`

3- `CFrameWnd::OnClose()`

which calls `CWinApp::CloseAllDocuments(BOOL bEndSession);`

which calls `CDocManager::CloseAllDocuments(BOOL bEndSession)`

which calls `CDocTemplate::CloseAllDocuments(BOOL)`

which calls `CDocument::OnCloseDocument()`

Now, in this function

```
while (!m_viewList.IsEmpty())
{
    // get frame attached to the view
    CView* pView = (CView*)m_viewList.GetHead();
    ASSERT_VALID(pView);
    CFrameWnd* pFrame = pView->EnsureParentFrame();

    // and close it
    PreCloseFrame(pFrame);
    pFrame->DestroyWindow();
    // will destroy the view as well
}
```

So we see that `CWnd::DestroyWindow()` is called, so:

4- `Derived CFormView destructor`

5- `CScrollView::~CScrollView()`

6- `CView::~CView()`

which calls `CDocument::RemoveView(CView* pView)`

which calls `CDocument::OnChangedViewList()`

which calls `CDocument::UpdateFrameCounts()`

Which crashes here: `ASSERT(::IsWindow(pView->m_hWnd));`

because `pView->m_hWnd` is `NULL`...

EDIT 3:

I figured out what the problem was:

The destructor of the first view was deleting an uninitialized pointer, which is UB. This was making the destructor hang and never complete.

Usually, the destructor of the second view is only called upon completion of the first one. But in this case it was still being executed although the first one never completed.

Since the first view base class destructors were never called, this function was never called for the first view:

```
void CDocument::RemoveView(CView* pView)
{
    ASSERT_VALID(pView);
    ASSERT(pView->m_pDocument == this); // must be attached to us

    m_viewList.RemoveAt(m_viewList.Find(pView));
    pView->m_pDocument = NULL;

    OnChangedViewList();    // must be the last thing done to the document
}
```

**Where we can see that the view is removed from the `m_viewList`**.

This means that when the second view destructor completes, in:

```
void CDocument::UpdateFrameCounts()
     // assumes 1 doc per frame
{
    // walk all frames of views (mark and sweep approach)
    POSITION pos = GetFirstViewPosition();
    while (pos != NULL)
    {
...
```

**The pos is supposed to be `NULL`, but it is not. Which lead to the crash.**

Comment: Try posting `WM_SYSCOMMAND` with a wParam of `SC_CLOSE` instead.

Comment: Nope, exact same issue, `pView->m_hWnd` is already `NULL` when it gets to `ASSERT(::IsWindow(pView->m_hWnd));`, it is actually `CFormView`s, I edited the question in case it changes anything.

Comment: At this point I'd put in some trace statements to get the order that things occur when you click the "X" yourself vs. when you send `WM_CLOSE` instead. That will shed some light on the process.

Comment: @MarkRansom see EDIT 2 for the order.

Comment: My suggestion was to compare that order to the order when you click on the "X" close button, to see if there's a difference.

Comment: Just tested and the "X" close button has the exact same behavior.

Comment: And if you try to close the app from menu->File->Exit command ? You get the same behavior ? If not, you can use ::PostMessage(AfxGetMainWnd()->m_hWnd, WM_COMMAND, ID_FILE_EXIT, 0L);

Comment: I bumped into something like this some years back. As I recall it I opted into the auto-destruct mechanism by overriding `PostNcDestroy` in the offending view, calling the base implementation and then doing `delete this`. Let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved, see EDIT 3 in the question for the solution.

Comment: The answer should not be in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I think the way you are closing the frame is not the issue there.
My guess is that you destroy one of the views by hand whereas you should let MFC delete them (you probably called DestroyWindow on one of them)

Answer (score 1):

Call `::PostQuitMessage(0);` to close the app.

Comment: If I use what you suggest, then the destructors of the derived CFormViews are never called...