# Exit app with returning code in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I trying to find any solution from 2 days, but i didn't find anything usefull.
I need to close my app from aplication code with returning value. I know, i need to use ExitInstance, it's work's fine but only when i add window and press X to close my app. I need to force my app to close from code (something like to fore ExitInstance). Any solutions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to programmatically quit an MFC application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562335/what-is-the-correct-way-to-programmatically-quit-an-mfc-application)

Answer (score 4):

Use the [PostQuitMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644945(v=vs.85).aspx) function, passing an appropriate exit code as its only argument, i.e.

```
PostQuitMessage(0); //Everything went fine
```

or

```
PostQuitMessage(-1); //Troubles occurred
```

Comment: I read on msdn: Return value

This function does not return a value.

Comment: This function **sets** the application return value.