# How can WIX Bundle bootstrapper receive the return code from MFC app

Tags: wix, bundle, bootstrapper

I have a wix bundle for testing that calls a Windows MFC dialog-based application (an EXE file.)
As that application has "Cancel" button, when the user clicks it, I want to make the bundle fail intentionally.
How can I do it?

Here is an excerpt from my app and I use `PostQuitMessage(1603)` but it doesn't work.

```
BOOL CBundleUtilApp::InitInstance()
{
...
    m_pMainWnd = &dlg;
    INT_PTR nResponse = dlg.DoModal();
    ...
    if( nResponse == IDCANCEL )
    {
        PostQuitMessage( 1603 );
    }

    m_pMainWnd = NULL;

    return FALSE;
}   // InitInstance()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to programmatically quit an MFC application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562335/what-is-the-correct-way-to-programmatically-quit-an-mfc-application)

Comment: Hi @Andrew, No, it isn't. The bundle app (aka bootstrapper) doesn't know and proceeds to the next item in the chain.

Comment: Override `CWinApp::ExitInstance()` to return the exit code you want.

Comment: Hi @zett42, That's it. After I did what you said, now the bootstrapper know it failed. Thank you.